# Modelling count data with variable upper bound

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, poisson-regression, latent-variable

I have been unable to find references to understand how count data can be modeled where each count observation has an unknown upper bound lying in a particular range.

Let's consider the following example so that I can make my problem statement clear:

In a study, a statistician is trying to model number of cigarettes each member of an office staff ($N_{members} = 45$) smokes on each day ($day$) through Monday to Friday for four weeks. The predictor variables used to model number of cigarettes ($N_{c})$ are weight ($w$), gender ($g$) and members' rating on a scale of 0 to 10 about their stress level ($stress$) assessed as soon as they enter the office on each day. It can be assumed that members of the office are very punctual and they reach the office exactly at the same time. All individuals carry their own cigarette packs and they do not share their cigarettes with each other.

However, it is known to the statistician that some members carry more packs than others but no one carries more than two packs. The statistician also knows that these packs have at most 10-14 cigarettes and knows the number of packs ($N_p$) each member carries every day.

More importantly, members who smoke more cigarettes on an average are expected to drop from the study within few days and those who don't smoke at all are expected to have high compliance with regards to reporting their $N_c$ to the statistician. From the previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631745/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-covariate-which-exists-only-for-specific-range-for) I had asked, I know that Generalized Linear Mixed Models (GLMMs) can handle unbalanced datasets.

Here is my naive model for understanding how predictor variables might affect $N_{c}$:

```r
fit <- lme4::glmer(Nc <- g + w + stress + day + offset(Np) + 
                   (1 | Member), family = poisson)
```

This model does not account for temporal autocorrelation in $N_c$ across days as well as is not well-informed about the number of data points observed for each member. How can I improve such model to account for count data where each observation has an uncertain upper bound lying in the range of 20-28? This problem is different than what was asked in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221737/can-you-use-the-poisson-glm-if-there-is-an-upper-limit) because of variable upper bound.

Comment: the first thing that pops into my head is to use a latent variable model, where there is a "number of packs" latent variable and a "cigarettes per pack" latent var associated with each individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key issue here is that there are latent (discrete) count variable that potentially take values from 10 to 14 for each pack of cigarettes a person has. We can make simplifying assumptions like that the packs a person has are always the same because they stay with the same brand, or that they would be the same on a day etc. - realistically, you'd also wonder about carrying over started packs to the next day, but I assume this is a toy problem to illustrate a concept. Each person then uses a number that is from some count distribution that cannot be higher than the sum of cigarettes they have on the day (which is a latent unknown variable).

One question would be what happens with the tail of the distribution beyond that number, for which there's multiple options. In this particular example, I'd speculate that if someone would have smoked 100 cigarettes, if they only could have, they would smoke all the ones they had on them. I.e. all the distributional weight of the distribution tail end up piling up on the number of cigarettes the person has on them. If we look at this that way, then you can consider all values corresponding to the maximum number of cigarettes per person to be left-censored to be $\geq$ to that value.

If we instead considered this as a case of truncation in the sense it's usually implemented, then the weight of the tail end of the distribution would be re-distributed across all numbers from 0 to the maximum number of cigarettes for a person.

Another question you may want to decide is whether you want to model the number of packs (and how much is in each pack) and what assumptions you are willing to make (about how related this is within person, across adjacent days etc.). If you make the effort, potentially you can recover more information from the main relationship of interest, on the other hand, if you make super-simple assumptions, the problem becomes easier. How so? If I assume that every day for each person the number of packs is i.i.d. drawn with equal probability from $\{0, 1, 2\}$, the number of cigarettes per pack is drawn from $\{10, 11, 12, 13, 14\}$ and nothing else about a person or what happens on other days can tell us anything of these values, then I can of course write down the resulting discrete mixture of Poisson distributions that then serves as our model likelihood (basically with probability 1/3 the outcome is 0, with 1/3 it's a mixture of 5 Poisson with censoring at $\geq \{10, 11, 12, 13, 14\}$ and with 1/3 it's a mixture of 5 Poisson with censoring at $\geq \{20, 21, 22, 23, 24\}$). That's a case where I can easily see how a marginalize out the latent discrete number of cigarettes a person has.

I don't think you can fit such a model with `lme4` or other common modeling packages, but anything that let's you write a custom likelihood could potentially cope with this, you will just have to deal with the fact that often the latent parameters are not identified in the data (potentially causing problems for maximum likelihood). One natural approach to take that can deal decently with non-identified nuisance parameters would be a Bayesian approach with proper priors. However, the discrete latent variable makes this slightly tricky. That's because e.g. the popular NUTS sampler in `Stan` does not cope with discrete parameters/latent variables - that is unless you manage to marginalize out the likelihood as above, in which case it's straightforward and just tedious to write down such a model in `Stan` or if you implement a custom likelihood in `brms`. Gibbs samplers (e.g. jags) should be able to handle the discrete latent variables, it may also be possible to approach this via ABC (approximate Bayesian computation, where you basically simulate the underlying process and keep realizations that [approximately] match the observed data) but I think that's less well suited to the problem.